# Fitting a reduced-form MA(3) time series model in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to fit an ARIMA model for a certain financial time series. I've used EViews for modeling, and have decided to fit a so-called reduced-form MA(3) model, where only the third lag is statistically significant.

Unfortunately, I have not been a to figure out how to do this in R. All I can find is how to fit a regular MA(3) model, using either the 'stats' or 'forecats' packages.

Can anyone please help me out? Thank you!

Comment: @Clay Please consider making your edits more substantive than a mere change of tags. Suggested edits on Stack Overflow should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post, such as e.g. grammar, code formatting, clarity, etc.

Comment: @senshin Really ...a comment for this? :P That is your own opinion.  You don't have to approve edits if you don't see them as a valid.  The tags provide a way for SO to automatically cluster/group related questions by tag.  Makes it easier to find related questions -- it makes it worthwhile to get the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

The argument 'fixed' could be useful in Arima function from the 'forecast' package:

```
library("forecast")
?Arima

# lets make some data
eps = rnorm(100)
x = filter(eps, c(0, 0, 0.2), "recursive")

# unrestricted Arima
Arima(x, order = c(3, 0, 0), include.mean = FALSE)
# restricted Arima
Arima(x, order = c(3, 0, 0), include.mean = FALSE, fixed=c(0,0,NA))
```

Comment: Don't know if it solves the problem but you have a `fixed` argument in `stats::arima` too

Comment: Looks promising, but how should I use the argument?